# Are there constructor references in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, function-reference, constructor-reference

In Java we have the `Class::new` syntax for constructor references. I know, there are callable references for methods, but how about constructors? A typical use case for me would be factories.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You can get a function instance for a constructor by simply using `::ClassName`, as if it were a factory function.

Comment: Much obliged. Idk if this will help anyone, but to do this with Sealed classes do: `SealedClass::SubClass`

Comment: What about references to secondary constructors?

Comment: @TravisWell what would be an equivalent in Java? AFAIK you can't reference specific constructor in Java. The compiler automatically detects which constructor to reference (through Class::new) by inferred (or explicit) argument types

Comment: @TravisWell you can specify value type for different constructors. For example, `val a: () -> A = ::A` or `val a: (Int) -> A = ::A`