# What is the proper way to create new instance of generic class in kotlin?

Tags: class, generics, kotlin

I use following initialization:

```
val entityClass = javaClass<Class<T>>()
var entity = entityClass.newInstance().newInstance()
```

but it's wrong and causes `IllegalAccessException` on `java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you let IntelliJ add explicit type information, you see that `entityClass` is actually of type `Class<Class<String>>`. I'm not sure if that's what you want. In line 2 you are first creating an instance of `Class<T>` and then one of `T` but that's not possible anyway, because the generic information about `T` is lost at runtime. Apart from that you can't instantiate class objects directly.

### Solution

One possible solution would be to add a parameter of type `Class<T>` to your function or class and use it to instantiate objects like this.

```
fun <T> foo(entityClass: Class<T>) {
    var entity: T = entityClass.newInstance()
}

fun test() {
    foo(Object::class.java)
}
```

But there's actually a more elegant solution without the use of reflection. Define a parameter of method type `() -> T` and use constructor references. [Here's my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472839/are-there-constructor-references-in-kotlin) about constructor references and here's the code:

```
fun <T> foo2(factory: () -> T) {
    var entity: T = factory()
}

fun test() {
    foo2(::Object)
}
```

Comment: hi, what if entityClass is Interface?

Comment: Is there a way to set a bound on the generic type that says "not an interface"?  C# has the `new` keyword for similar behavior, to say "T must be constructable".

Comment: I guess you can omit `entityClass` by making the function inline with reified.

Comment: How can attributes be added to the Object when created in the *foo* function?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [Kirill Rakhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman) I wrote a similar answer (for Android adapter). A difference here is in a parameter of the class.

```
private fun <T> createItem(
    viewGroup: ViewGroup,
    layoutRes: Int,
    method: (View) -> T
): T {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(layoutRes, viewGroup, false)
    return method(view) // Creates T(view).
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AbstractViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        LOADER -> createItem(viewGroup, R.layout.row_loader, ::LoaderViewHolder)
        DATE -> createItem(viewGroup, R.layout.row_date, ::DateViewHolder)
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Wrong class")
    }
}
```

Here `LoaderViewHolder` and `DateViewHolder` are descendants of `AbstractViewHolder`.