# Kotlin generics Array<T> results in "Cannot use T as a reified type parameter. Use a class instead" but List<T> does not

Tags: java, arrays, generics, kotlin, reification

I have an interface that contains an array (or list) of T and some metadata.

```
interface DataWithMetadata<T> {
    val someMetadata: Int
    fun getData(): Array<T>
}
```

If I write the simplest implementation of the interface, I get a compile error on the `emptyArray()`: "Cannot use T as a reified type parameter. Use a class instead."

```
class ArrayWithMetadata<T>(override val someMetadata: Int): DataWithMetadata<T> {
    private var myData: Array<T> = emptyArray()

    override fun getData(): Array<T> {
        return myData
    }

    fun addData(moreData: Array<T>) {
        this.myData += moreData
    }
}
```

However, if I change both the interface and the implementation to a list, I have no compile-time issues:

```
interface DataWithMetadata<T> {
    val someMetadata: Int
    fun getData(): List<T>
}

class ListWithMetadata<T>(override val someMetadata: Int): DataWithMetadata<T> {
    private var myData: List<T> = emptyList()

    override fun getData(): List<T> {
        return myData
    }

    fun addData(moreData: Array<T>) {
        this.myData += moreData
    }
}
```

I suspect there is some interesting lesson in Kotlin generics inside my issue. Can anyone tell me what the compiler is doing under the hood and why Array fails but List does not? Is there an idiomatic way to make the Array implementation compile in this context?

Bonus question: The only reason I reached for Array over List is that I often see Kotlin developers favor Arrays. Is this the case, and if so, why?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Looking at the declaration of `emptyArray()` in the kotlin stdlib (jvm), we notice the `reified` type parameter:

```
public inline fun <reified @PureReifiable T> emptyArray(): Array<T>
```

The `reified` type parameter means that you have access to the class of `T` at compile-time and can access it like `T::class`. You can read more about `reified` type parameters in the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). Since `Array<T>` compiles to java `T[]`, we need to know the type at compile-time, hence the `reified` parameter. If you try writing an emptyArray() function without the `reified` keyword, you'll get a compiler error:

```
fun <T> emptyArray() : Array<T> = Array(0, { throw Exception() })
```

> Cannot use T as a reified type parameter. Use a class instead.

---

Now, let's take a look at the implementation of `emptyList()`:

```
public fun <T> emptyList(): List<T> = EmptyList
```

This implementation doesn't need the parameter `T` at all. It just returns the internal object `EmptyList`, which itself inherits from `List<Nothing>`. The kotlin type `Nothing` is the return-type of the `throw` keyword and is *a value that never exists* ([reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html)). If a method returns `Nothing`, is is equivalent to throwing an exception at that place. So we can safely use `Nothing` here because everytime we would call `EmptyList.get()` the compiler knows that this will return an exception.

---

**Bonus question:**

Coming from Java and C++, I am used to `ArrayList` or `std::vector` to be far easier to use that arrays. I use kotlin now for a few month and I usually don't see a big difference between arrays and lists when writing source code. Both have tons of useful extension functions which behave in a similar way. However, the Kotlin compiler handles arrays and lists very different, as Java interoperability is very important for the Kotlin team. I usually prefer using lists, and that's what I'd recommend in your case too.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that the generic type of an `Array` must be known at *compile time*, which is indicated by the `reified` type parameter here, as seen in the declaration:

```
public inline fun <reified @PureReifiable T> emptyArray(): Array<T>
```

It's only possible to create concrete arrays like `Array<String>` or `Array<Int>` but not of type `Array<T>`.

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41946516/8073652), you can find several workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

I got `Type parameter T cannot be called as function` when tried to return T.

```
private fun <T> getData(): T {
    return T()
}
```

See [What is the proper way to create new instance of generic class in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992039/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-new-instance-of-generic-class-in-kotlin):

```
private fun <T> create(
    method: (Int) -> T,
    value: Int
): T {
    return method(value) // Creates T(value).
}

// Usage:

create(::ClassName, 1)
```

where `ClassName` extends `T`.

Also maybe this will help:

```
private inline fun <reified T> getData(): T {
    return T::class.java.newInstance()
}
```

But in my case I had to return `T(parameter)`, not `T()`, so, didn't try. See also [How to get class of generic type parameter in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446900/how-to-get-class-of-generic-type-parameter-in-kotlin).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that worked best for me was:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
var pool: Array<T?> = arrayOfNulls<Any?>(initialCapacity) as Array<T?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble in the solution above. Here is what I came up with using [`typeOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) from [kotlin-reflect](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html):

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private inline fun <reified T> createArrayOfGeneric(): Array<T> {
    return java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(typeOf<T>().javaType as Class<*>, 10) as Array<T>
}
```

The `newInstance` method takes the java type as class of the generic that you get from `typeOf`, and the second parameter is the length of the array.

Answer (score -2):

I changed it from `Array<T>` to `ArrayList<T>` and it worked.