# Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

/**
this "T::class.java" report an error :Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead!
so how can i fix it or what can i do to realize this way?please.
**/
see the next kotlin code

```
data class PostHttpResultBean<T>(private var errno:Int,private var error:String,private var data:String):IHttpResultEntity<T>{
override val errorCode: Int
    get() = errno
override val errorMessage: String
    get() = error
override val isSuccess: Boolean
    get() = errno==0
override val result:T
    get() = RSAUtil.dataDecrypt(RSAUtil.getKeyPassword(), data,T::class.java)!!

class RSAUtil {
companion object {
fun <T> dataDecrypt(password: String, data: String, java: Class<T>): T? {
    val content = Base64.decode(data.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
    try {
        var deString = decrypt(content, password)
        if (!deString.isEmpty()){
            val first = deString.substring(0, deString.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)
            deString = "$first$deString}"
            return Gson().fromJson(deString,java)
        }

        return null
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return null
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: may be you need to use `reified @PureReifiable`. look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870546/6055194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `dataDecrypt` like that:

```
inline fun <reified T> dataDecrypt(password: String, data: String): T? {
     ...
     try {
          ...
          if (!deString.isEmpty()){
              ...
              return Gson().fromJson(deString, T::class.java)
          }
          ...
     }
 }
```

And on the call site the `T` type will be inferred from `result`:

```
override val result:T
get() = RSAUtil.dataDecrypt(RSAUtil.getKeyPassword(), data)!!
```

You can read more about inline functions and reified types [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) and I strongly recommend to do so. I would also point out that your code is ill-formatted, it is advised to use `?:` instead of `!!` in [nullability checks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) and companion objects are discouraged in Kotlin, you could define functions outside of class and use (or import) them as if they were static.