# Kotlin: Double Colon vs. Lambda in similarish Class

Tags: kotlin

I understand my first second example uses a lambda function with a single parameter passed in. I'm trying to understand why it would be different from my second boilerplate example where a double colon is used instead of a lambda. (still a kotlin newb trying to wrap my head around double colons coming from a python background)

```
class Service(services: PluginServiceHub) {
    init {
        services.registerFlowInitiator(Landlord::class.java) { Landlord(it) }
    }
}
```

VS

```
class Service(services: PluginServiceHub) {
    init {
        services.registerFlowInitiator(IssuanceRequester::class.java, ::Issuer)
    }
}
```

What does the `::Issuer` represent exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming there is a class `Issuer`, `::Issuer` will be [a function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to its constructor. A constructor taking the appropriate number of arguments (one in this case) will be resolved and used, which is equivalent to a lambda `{ Issuer(it) }`.

If there's no such a class, a function named `Issuer` and taking one argument will be used, if it exists.

See: [Are there constructor references in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472839/are-there-constructor-references-in-kotlin)

Comment: this is a very simple and clarifying explanation. thank you!